How to add Metadata to Razor Page view
With MinimalApi you can register MetaData with the route like below.
app.MapGet("test-slow-route", async () => { await Task.Delay(1000); return Results.Ok("Ok"); })
   .WithMetadata(new SystemAccessRoute());

and then query this from the endpoint
var endpoint = context.GetEndpoint();

return endpoint.Metadata.GetMetadata<SystemAccessRoute>() != null;

How do you add metadata to a razor page that can be discovered in middleware or really anywhere with a HttpContext?

Hi @BillRob, what is your scenraio to add the metadata to razor pages? You can add it to HttpContext.Items["PageMetadata"] = metadata; in the OnGet method in the endpoint you want.
